# How to create two new iterators based on a pandas read csv iterator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, neural-network, tf.keras

I'm attempting to train a neural network, using Keras. My dataset is quite large and I have limited RAM so I can't read all the data in at once.

So instead, I'm using pandas to read a csv in chunks, like so:

```
df_iterator = pandas.read_csv("./formated_data/data-09-11-22.csv", chunksize=32, iterator=True)
```

The data read in is in the form:

input data 1, input data 2, input data 3, ..... , input data 3600, expected output

So 36001 elements compose a single row in the csv file.

I have approximately 425,000 rows.

As keras' fit function is as follows:

```
history = model.fit(Inputs, Outputs, validation_split=0.33, epochs=200, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
```

I need to know how I can split my original iterator into two, one for the input data and one for the expected output? without requiring too much additional RAM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I tried the following function to split the original iterator, but as my knowledge of python is limited, I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing. Or if it significantly increases RAM requirements. You may have a totally different approach.

```
def split(iterable, n):
    iterators = []
    for i, iterator in enumerate(itertools.tee(iterable, n)):
        iterators.append(itertools.map(operator.itemgetter(i),iterator))
    return tuple(iterators)
```

Comment: Do you mean splitting each iterator of `chunksize=32` into 2 iterators of size `16` ?

Comment: Nope, Each dataframe consists of 36001 elements. 36000 input data, and 1 output. The above iterator will return all 36001, but the model.fit function requires 2 iterators. 1 for input and 1 for output. So I need to split that 36001 iterator into one iterator that returns the 36000 elements of input data, and I need a seperate iterator that will return the 1 output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `usecols` argument of `read_csv` to create an iterator with only the columns you need.

First create an iterator over the features:

```
>>> data_36001_X_10 = '\n'.join([','.join(['0']*36000 + ['1'])] * 10)
>>> buf = io.StringIO(data_36001_X_10)
>>> for chunk in pandas.read_csv(buf, chunksize=2, usecols=range(36000), header=None):
...   print(chunk)
...   print()
... 
   0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11     12     13     ...  35986  35987  35988  35989  35990  35991  35992  35993  35994  35995  35996  35997  35998  35999
0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

[2 rows x 36000 columns]

   0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11     12     13     ...  35986  35987  35988  35989  35990  35991  35992  35993  35994  35995  35996  35997  35998  35999
2      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
3      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

[2 rows x 36000 columns]
```

then create an iterator only over the labels:

```
>>> buf = io.StringIO(data_36001_X_10)
>>> for chunk in pandas.read_csv(buf, chunksize=2, usecols=[36000], header=None):
...   print(chunk, sep='\n')
...   print()
... 
   36000
0      1
1      1

   36000
2      1
3      1

   36000
4      1
5      1

   36000
6      1
7      1

   36000
8      1
9      1
```

`usecols=range(36000)` fetches the columns on position 0 to 35999. `usecols=[36000]` only fetches data from the last column.